# UPDATE is not working after long sleep

Tags: php, mysql, sleep

I have the following `php` code:

```
sleep(65);      
$query = "UPDATE database.table SET XXXXXXX = XXXXXXX - ".$YYYYYY." WHERE ZZZZZZZZ = '1111111111111111111'";
mysql_query($query);
```

The `UPDATE` is not working and I really need it after the 65 second `sleep`.

Any idea on how to do it? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` show after `mysql_query()`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. whoan... No error shown. If I comment the sleep it works. Otherwise the update it is not performed. If I reduce the sleep time to 5 seconds it works. But I need to sleep the process during 65 seconds at least.

Comment: Please check the `default_socket_timeout` value in your php.ini. It defaults to 60 seconds (see php.net/default-socket-timeout)

Comment: I edited in my php code the sleep to sleep(60) and, following the instructions found at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-settings-on-ubuntu-14-04, I edited the php.ini max_execution_time from 30 to 60; I restarted the server. No updates are made yet.

Comment: look for the `default_socket_timeout` variable instead of `max_execution_time`.

Comment: @whoan. I did look for default_socket_timeout. It is 60 seconds. Any recommendation? should I edit it?

Comment: You can change that value or re/connect to the database after the `sleep`

Comment: use redis or rabbitmq for queue with delay, it's will be better than sleep 65

Answer (score 1):

Is PHP running under apache?

IIRC, typical PHP.ini files within server configurations will set a max_execution_time of some form. Maybe you're running into this limit?

Comment: Under Linux sleep() time is ignored so max_execution_time refers to real running time, not including sleeping time

Comment: @JorgeSB, ah, I see. That makes sense now.